# Entity Framework - adding simple Entity to the context is very slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to populate my database with "fake" data in order to perform some stress test on it.
Therefor, I have written some simple straightforward code to enter data.
It runs over 7 tables, creates an object for each one, and add it using :

```
System.Data.Entity.Add(TEntity)
```

As follows:

```
context.MyObject.Add(MyObjInstance);
```

And I save every few hundred objects.

Now this is way to slow, even without the commit. (I mean hours for a very few thousand objects).
Is there a faster way to add (around a few thousand) objects ?
Something like `addAll()`, or anything else that will speed up the `Add` method?
Thanks.

Comment: why don't u do it with a database script directly ?

Answer (score 4):

It may be because of repeated calls to `DetectChanges()`. Some EF functions automatically call this method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx).

> If you are tracking a lot of entities in your context and you call one
>   of these methods many times in a loop, then you may get significant
>   performance improvements by turning off detection of changes for the
>   duration of the loop

Set

`context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

Do your intensive `.Add()` operations and set:

`context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;`

before calling `SaveChanges()`.

Also consider using a new context for part of the bulk operations as the more entities a context tracks the worse it performs.

Comment: Tried it. the adds runs fast but now the SaveChanges() takes a lot of time :-) (I have a feeling that is takes the same amount in total)

Comment: Do not call context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true,  and Dispose of the Context.